# Java Script shortcut error

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying a course on codeacademy. This code is supposed to trigger an article to open when the O-key (111) is pressed. But I'm told that,

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }"

Here is my code, anyone able to offer some advice?

```
var main = function() {

$('article').click(function() {

        $('article').removeclass('current');

        $('description').hide();

        $(this).addclass('current');

        $('article').click(function() {

        $(this).children('.description').show(

            });

    $(document).keypress(function(event) {

        if(event.which === 111) {

            $('.current').children('.description').toggle();

        }

    });

    $(document).ready(main);
```

I am also told that: "It looks like the o key isn't opening a description. Remember to toggle the current article's description inside the event handler. Look back at the instructions for the code." Thanks

Comment: Check all your closing brackets and parenthesis. You have several typos.

Comment: Use [JSHint](http://jshint.com) to help find errors

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `)`

```
    var main = function() {

    $('article').click(function() {

    $('article').removeclass('current');

    $('description').hide();

    $(this).addclass('current');

    $('article').click(function() {

    $(this).children('.description').show(); // you missed the ) here

        });

$(document).keypress(function(event) {

    if(event.which === 111) {

        $('.current').children('.description').toggle();

    }

});

$(document).ready(main);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, now i've been hit with an "Unexpected end to output"....any suggestions?

var main = function() {
    
$('article').click(function() {

        $('article').removeclass('current');

        $('description').hide();

        $(this).addclass('current');

        $('article').click(function() {

        $(this).children('.description').show();

            });

    $(document).keypress(function(event) {

        if(event.which === 111) {

            $('.current').children('.description').toggle();

                }
    });
    
    
 
        $(document).ready(main);

Answer (score 1):

Your code had mismatched paretheses and brackets. Consider using [JSHint](http://jshint.com) to help you find errors. Fixed code. Also consider indenting your code properly. It will help you find typos faster.

```
var main = function() {
    $('article').click(function() {
        $('article').removeclass('current');
        $('description').hide();
        $(this).addclass('current');
        $('article').click(function() {
            $(this).children('.description').show()
        });
        $(document).keypress(function(event) {
            if(event.which === 111) {
                $('.current').children('.description').toggle();
            }
        });
    });
}
$(document).ready(main);
```

Answer (score 0):

These errors are frustrating but you get better with time.

Note that you haven't closed some of your parenthesis (ie. show() )

**edit;** because above user Trevor did a stellar job spotting the error before me, I'm going to see if I can't add a bit more value to my post.

Because you missed the paren in the .show() method, the interpreter found the **}** as an *argument* inside of the show method.

ie. .show(**}**).

Because the .show() method does not take any arguments, it resulted in an error in your code. Hopefully that helps your understanding!

For example:

```
 var main = function() {

  $('article').click(function() {

    $('article').removeclass('current');

    $('description').hide();

    $(this).addclass('current');

    $('article').click(function() {

    $(this).children('.description').show(**)**

        });

$(document).keypress(function(event) {

    if(event.which === 111) {

        $('.current').children('.description').toggle();

    }

});

$(document).ready(main);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, now i've been hit with an "Unexpected end to output"....any suggestions?

var main = function() {
    
$('article').click(function() {

        $('article').removeclass('current');

        $('description').hide();

        $(this).addclass('current');

        $('article').click(function() {

        $(this).children('.description').show();

            });

    $(document).keypress(function(event) {

        if(event.which === 111) {

            $('.current').children('.description').toggle();

                }
    });
    
    
 
        $(document).ready(main);